# How to get query param from URL string in VBS

Tags: string, parsing, url, vbscript

I am getting as XML which contains a URL with some query param so is there any way to get those param other then string parsing in vbscript.

**For example:**

```
<response>
<url>www.example.com?a=abc&b=xyz&c=pqr</url>
</response>
```

After parsing and getting url from Xml, I want to get the query param values of a,b,c etc.

Comment: Any chance you work online on this? If so, you could post contents of your <url> tag to your own site then collect posted vars.

Comment: Yes I did and I found HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Urlstring), however It seems, It is not working.

Comment: Please, share your code for us to help. Thanks.

Comment: I am referring https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use XML DOM methods and XPath to retrieve url node and it's content.

Comment: There is no built-in way in vbscript to get the values out of the URL besides parsing the string. Keep in mind that HttpUtility.ParseQueryString will work in VB, however, it will *not* work in VBScript.

Comment: Thanks everyone and yes I did the string parsing.